# SQL query required to count records

Tags: mysql

My scenario is this. I need to provide the names of students and the number of specific grades they have acheived (in this case grade A). Consider the first query as:

```
SELECT studentID, fullname
FROM tblStudents
```

The next query is:

```
SELECT studentID, grade, Count(grade) AS CountOfGrade
FROM tblResults
GROUP BY studentID, grade
HAVING grade="A";
```

I can combine these so that I can show the number of A grades for each student by joining the query:

```
SELECT tblStudents.studentID, tblStudents.fullname, tblResults.grade, Count(tblResults.grade) AS CountOfGrade
FROM tblStudents INNER JOIN tblResults ON tblStudents.studentID = tblResults.studentID 
GROUP BY tblStudents.fullname, tblResults.grade
HAVING tblResults.grade="A";
```

However it does not return the names of students who do not have a grade A, only a students who have at least 1. I have tried a LEFT join as opposed to INNER but this does not seem to help.

How can I achieve this, so that I get the zero counts too? Eg:

```
Name    Grade   GradeCount
Bob     A       1
Jim     A       0 
Sarah   A       4
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `LEFT JOIN` to a derived table produced by the second query:

```
SELECT t1.studentID, 
       t1.fullname, 
       'A' AS grade, 
       COALESCE(t2.CountOfGrade, 0) AS CountOfGrade
FROM tblStudents AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT studentID, COUNT(grade) AS CountOfGrade
   FROM tblResults
   WHERE grade = 'A'
   GROUP BY studentID
) AS t2 ON t1.studentID = t2.studentID
```

**Note:** Grouping by `grade` field is actually not necessary since you want only `grade = 'A'` records. You can simply use a `WHERE` clause instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. Really helpful and I got there in the end. Just out of interest do you have to change the table names?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a subselect too, if the field grade always be equals  to the parameter :GRADE.

```
SELECT NAME, :GRADE GRADE , 
       (SELECT COUNT(1) 
          FROM GRADES 
         WHERE GRADE = :GRADE 
           AND GRADES.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID) GRADECount  
  FROM STUDENTS S
```

Now the query like you want, with parametergrade 'A':

```
SELECT NAME, 'A' GRADE , 
       (SELECT COUNT(1) 
          FROM GRADES 
         WHERE GRADE = 'A'
           AND GRADES.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID) GRADECount  
 FROM STUDENTS S
```